# Should one use resistors to protect an mbed when using it to simulate keyboard key presses

Tags: resistors, protection, mbed

One can use mbed to act as USB Host or as a USB Device. One use of the latter is to have it emulate a USB Keyboard by sending normal key presses. The general page on using mbed as a USB Device is in their handbook here: https://mbed.org/handbook/USBDevice But looking at the photos of completed projects on that page, for example the one below, they do not use any resistors to protect the mbed from power errors coming over the USB connection.

[image: mbed as USB Device]

Is that how one should do it? Would it be better to include protection and if so what would the amended schema/diagram be?

Comment: What sort of errors did you mean? You can't put resistors in the power or data path without breaking the connection in critical ways. The best you can do is protect it against electrostatic discharge, although it may have inbuilt protection.

Comment: I'm not sure pjc50, but power surges was what I had in mind. How should one protect it from electrostatic discharge?

Comment: (N.B. I'm not sure why this question has been down-voted. It's good practise, especially for electronics beginners like myself, if whoever down-votes explains how the question could be improved.)

Comment: You can get "transient voltage suppression" devices, which are basically special Zener diodes. Connect them between the lines and ground. In practice you don't really need these for benchtop work, and most hobbyist devices include some protection of their own. Anything that's a proper USB supply will not emit voltage spikes in normal operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pjc50 said, you can't put resistors in the power or data of the USB without interfering with the communication.

If you want to avoid any damage to the USB port, I'd recommend **leaving disconnected** the VCC pin of the USB breakout board, powering the MBED with a different power source. You will prevent any shortcircuit due to incorrect wiring.